# How to create responsive images for hybrid mobile application

Tags: css, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid, multi-device-hybrid-apps

For hybrid mobile application that using:

- Foundation framework for supporting tablet and mobile
- "rem" for the font responsive

What is the best way to create responsive for images, now we give the images size in pix, the question is if the image re-size automatically for every device?

In Android for example there is dp for different resolution, I am looking for the same idea for hybrid mobile application.

what is the best image type for hybrid application? SVG, png...

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use a responsive css framework(like Bootstrap 3 or Foundation) and design seamless responsive web-pages that you can render in any os in web-views like the amazon app does(or used to do..haven't checked it in a while). The images can have % based dimensions..plus these frameworks have classes for responsive images as well.